# How to check if files in a path are of a particular type (in VB script)?

Tags: vbscript

I currently have a batch file which calls a vbscript that actually does the work I need (coz I have no experience with doing batch files). Take note, I just got this code off the internet.

**What I want to happen in the VB Script**
Basically, I will provide a path and the code will check if specific files (either CSV or XML) exist. If these files exist, they will be placed in a zip file.

**What is happening in the VB Script** Currently, the vbscript will get all the files in the path provided and all of it will be zipped into one file. I want to change this code so that it will only zip files that are CSV for example.

---

Batch code

```
CScript czip.vbs "C:\Users\donatoma\Documents\Folder1\" "C:\Users\donatoma\Documents\Folder2\CSV files.zip"
```

---

VB Script

```
'Get command-line arguments.
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
InputFolder = objArgs(0)
ZipFile = objArgs(1)

'Create empty ZIP file.
CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile(ZipFile, True).Write "PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, vbNullChar)

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

Set source = objShell.NameSpace(InputFolder).Items <-- GET CSV FILES, ADD TO AN ARRAY

objShell.NameSpace(ZipFile).CopyHere(source)

'Required!
wScript.Sleep 2000
```

**UPDATED CODE**

```
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
InputFolder = objArgs(0)
ZipFile = objArgs(1)

'Create empty ZIP file.
CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile(ZipFile, True).Write "PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, vbNullChar)

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

Set source = objShell.NameSpace(InputFolder).Items

For i = 0 to source.Count - 1
    If InStr(".csv", Right(source.item(i).Name, 4)) > 0 Then
        objshell.Namespace(ZipFile).CopyHere (source.item(i))
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the name.

```
CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile(ZipFile, True).Write "PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, vbNullChar)

Set objshell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

Set Source = objshell.Namespace(InputFolder).Items 

For i = 0 To Source.Count - 1
    If InStr(".csv,.xml", Right(Source.item(i).Name, 4)) > 0 Then
        objshell.Namespace(ZipFile).CopyHere (Source.item(i))
        WScript.Sleep 200
    End If 
Next
```

Comment: I tried the code but nothing happens. Let me just post the code I used just in case...

Comment: I guess you need to add sleep to the loop.

Comment: Where exactly? And what does **sleep** do?

Comment: I have illustrated where exactly above. Sleep pauses for the stated amount of time. I tested with 200, but less might work.